# Swift5 @dynamicMemberLookup function

Tags: swift

@dynamicMemberLookup subscript function.
no use parameterName is Error.
why?
@dynamicCallable is OK.

```
    @dynamicMemberLookup
    struct DynamicMember {
        // OK.
        subscript(dynamicMember string: String) -> String {
            return string
        }
        // NG.
        // none parameterName func. Why error?
        // @dynamicMemberLookup attribute requires 'Dynamic' to have a 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' method that accepts either 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral' or a keypath
        /*
        subscript(dynamicMember: String) -> String {
            return dynamicMember
        }
        */
    }

    let dm = DynamicMember()
    print(dm.dynamicProperty)
```

@dynamicCallable no parameter name OK.

```
    @dynamicCallable
    struct DynamicCall {
        // OK.
        func dynamicallyCall(withArguments list: [Int]) -> [Int] {
            return list
        }
        // OK.
        // none parameterName func.
        // dynamicCallable is OK.
        /*
        func dynamicallyCall(withArguments: [Int]) -> [Int] {
            return withArguments
        }
        */
    }

    let dc = DynamicCall()
    print(dc(1, 2, 3))
```

Compiler bug?
Please tell me who you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamicallyCall` is a function, but `dynamicMemberLookup` is a subscript, which has variations. It is done intentionally

a) to allow key path access (for your example)

```
print(dm[dynamicMember: "dynamicProperty"])
```

b) but to disallow ambiguous, something like

```
dm["dynamicProperty"]
```

See official details [on Swift Evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0252-keypath-dynamic-member-lookup.md)